# Firestore query "in" documentId

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to do something like this

```
firestore.doc(`cities`).where('documentId', 'in', ['123', '456'])
```

Where the documentId is the "primary key" for each city?

Comment: I'm assuming the `doc` here is a typo, and should be `collection('cities')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Use [FieldPath.documentId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#documentid).

```
firestore
    .doc(`cities`)
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ['123', '456'])
```